# CCS GRID question about text fitting into the div

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to create something like this.....

[image]

However, when i put text in one of the grid items.. the div stretches like this

[image]

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the relevant CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add grid-template-columns in your css like this:-

```
<style>

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
</div>
```